# Toolbar is invisible on some devices

Tags: android, toolbar, android-appcompat

I have a quite simple layout and I animate the showing/hiding of the toolbars with the appended functions. I'm using AppCompat and Toolbars...

**PROBLEM**

One person reported that the top toolbar is never shown. Any ideas why? What could be the reason? It's working fine on my phone and others...

**Function**

```
public void showHideToolbar(boolean forceHide, boolean animate)
{
    L.d(this, "showHideToolbar: " + mShowToolbar);
    toolbar.clearAnimation();
    toolbar2.clearAnimation();
    if (mShowToolbar || forceHide)
    {
        if (animate) {
            toolbar.animate().translationY(-toolbar.getBottom()).setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator()).start();
            toolbar2.animate().translationY(toolbar2.getBottom()).setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator()).start();
        }
        else
        {
            toolbar.setTranslationY(-toolbar.getBottom());
            toolbar2.setTranslationY(toolbar2.getBottom());
        }
        mShowToolbar = false;
    }
    else
    {
        if (animate) {
            toolbar.animate().translationY(0).setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator()).start();
            toolbar2.animate().translationY(0).setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator()).start();
        }
        else
        {
            toolbar.setTranslationY(0);
            toolbar2.setTranslationY(0);
        }
        mShowToolbar = true;
    }
}
```

**Layout**

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/flMain"
    android:background="?attr/main_background_color"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        app:theme="?actionBarThemeStyle"
        app:popupTheme="?actionBarPopupThemeStyle" />

    <android.support.v4.view
        android:id="@+id/vpSlides"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/bottom_bar_background"
        android:elevation="0dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:gravity="top|start"
        app:theme="?actionBarThemeStyle"
        app:popupTheme="?actionBarPopupThemeStyle" >

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like, even if you make a toolbar to an actionbar, you have to respect layout ordering in the xml. `setSupportActionBar` won't bring the action bar on top of the main layout...

So the simple solution was to reorder the toolbar to being under the content...

I never ad problems yet as normally I show the content underneath the toolbar, here I didn't want to that and therefore faced the problem